# Configuration quotes on variables in PHP

Tags: php, apache, centos, config, quote

I'm new on the site (hi!) and I had a problem that I can't resolve yet. I look for it, but no results... I think it's a stupid thing, but I can't find the solution.

I'm migrating a system (PHP) to other server (both are [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)) and I have a problem with the quotes in PHP variables:

```
    Example:
    --------
    $_GET[var]
    $db_reg[assoc]
    $array[value]
    define(NAME,'value')
    etc..
```

All cases can fix adding quotes to indexes, but I have thousand of PHP files, with millions of lines each one, and I can't check one by one... it will take around two lives and a half.

In the old server, it works normally, but in the new, the variables are not recognized, shows a PHP notice:

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant XXXX - assumed 'XXXX in..."
> (ej: $_POST[XXXX])

Is there a configuration in Apache or PHP for recognizing or not (indistinct) quotes on variables?

The PHP version on both servers are the same, and I have checked the *php.ini* file, and they are similar.

Comment: I think the best way to solve this would be to convert all the old scripts to use quotes. I know that sounds scary and doing it one-at-a-time manually is likely not feasible based on your description. It could be a fun programming challenge to scan all the source code and change all occurrences of [something] to ['something']. Of course you would have to have exceptions for [$something], etc. But that is the right way to do it now (and has always been, actually). Anything else would be a workaround that PHP might eventually do away with.

Comment: I know, the correct way is to change everything.. but the system is old and obsolete, in fact, I'm remaking it starting from zero.. so, I do not consider it necessary, I want to bury definitely... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need some information about variables and their usage (when working with arrays) and fixed index concretions.

Usage of variables:

```
$array = array('hi', 'you', 'there');
$i = 1;
echo $array[$i]; // -> Works and is **fine** (will output 'you')

// --------------------------------

$array = array('a' => 'hi', 'b' => 'you', 'c' => 'there');
echo $array['a']; // -> Works and is **fine**
// Note: in especially that case **NEVER** use barewords like this: echo $array[a] for >> a << here is expected to be a constant which (mostly) does not exist!
// PHP is so fuzzy that it will mostly interpret around like insane and output you the desired value ('hi' in that case), but that was never meant to be! And should always be prevented. That's the reason for you getting that notice...

// So never do this:
echo $array[a];
// ... if >> a << is NOT a valid and available constant
```

Important (summed up to the point):

Words without quotes and the dollar are considered constants which you perhaps do not use very often. In most cases, you use quotes (like described above) or real variables (identified by `$`) as index to access data structures/arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But is any way to config (apache, php, etc) for recognize without quotes? I can't change every vars on the system. Why in old server works perfectly and the new one fails? There must be something that I miss.... Thanks

Comment: @Daniel You are welcome. Please mark the answer which helps you out of the problem as "Solution". This makes people who got the same problem and find your question be able to easily determine the answer for their problem too.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll keep that in mind when you find the solution :)

Comment: Ah, now I see the aim of your question. Sorry. If I now understand you correct you are wanting to change PHP-language constructs/the way php interprets script-code. So as if you would be trying for example to define a "ret" as alias or replacement for "return". I do not think you can bring back this to php when using a recent version. Perhaps using a old version on the new server is the only way to achieve your goal. There are webserver modules out there enabling you to load older PHP version for specified script I guess. But this would at least require you being Server administrator.

Comment: In both servers the PHP Version is 5.3.3. I don't replace or make alias (like example that you said), I just need to php recognize vars without quotes, $_POST[value] instead $_POST['value'] for example... Thanks!

Comment: I tested it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Alh0Oq and it works. Without the "@" I am reported the same warning as you wrote down in the first post, but too I get the right output "foo". That test also ran on php 5.3.3. So whats exactly the problem in your case? Do some bareword-variables work and some not? Or do none of them work?

Comment: I just tested it and seems that works! Maybe I had issues when I used define(NAME,'value') instead of define('NAME','value') with quotes, and I assumed that the other vars also failed. As I said, the system is too big and I didn't do it.. so I have to keep checking what can be the problem... I was sure that the problem came for that way... Thank you! I mark this answer, right?

Comment: Glad I could help you out a little bit :) And thanks for the upvote :) Please let us know what the problem was exactly when you found out

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try editing the *php.ini* file:

Change

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

This will disable all notices, but I am not sure sure if this will get your issue resolved. Please try and let us know if this is working or not for you.

Comment: Its not the right way to suppress warnings because they are printed for a reason. The right way is more to fix the reason that causes php to print out a warning. Never the less this beats people to learn writing more clean code

Comment: Thanks! But my problem isn't to print the warning or notice.. the problem is that the system the system doesn't work properly due to the vars without quotes... I need to activate something like "recognize vars without quotes"